# Empty line appearing in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to generate a HTML email, where I am trying to prevent a record(tr) from getting displayed when there is no value present in both the cells.

```
table td :empty { 
    display:none; 
}
```

When I use the above snippet, the line containing the empty cells is not displayed when the html is opened in browser. However, when the same thing is sent in outlook, empty line is visible.

If outlook does not support this display feature, what is the alternative?

Comment: Have you try set a class or put inline the direct rule display:none;

Comment: no class, its put inline

Comment: can you put your code?